# How to break down 2-3-4 tree in OCAML

Tags: ocaml, red-black-tree, 2-3-4-tree

I want to break down a 2-3-4 tree to small nodes.

These are the types I am using:

```ml
        type ele = int 
        type color = Red|Black
        type ab = Vide | Node of ( ele * color * ab * ab *ab) 
        type ab234 = Vide
        |Node_1 of (ele * ab234* ab234)
        |Node_2 of(ele * ele * ab234 *ab234 *ab234) ``
        |Node_3 of(ele * ele * ele *ab234 * ab234* ab234 *ab234)
```

I based my mapping on this:

[image: 2-3-4 tree to bicolor]

I need help doing my transformation. I tried with this function but it doesn't seem to work, it does break down the root but it doesn't continue to the branches:

```ml
    let rec eclat = function
    | Vide -> Vide 
    | Node_3(r,x,y,ag,mg,md,ad) -> eclat ( Node_1(x,(Node_1(r,ag,mg)),Node_1(y,md,ad)))
    | Node_2(r,x,ag,ml,ad) -> eclat(Node_1(r,(Node_1(x,ag,ml)),ad))
    | _ -> failwith("zebi") ;;
```

Comment: StackOverflow is mostly for getting help  with a specific problems you're having with some code. Otherwise it's like  you're asking others to write your homework for you. So you should start by writing some code to do your transformation, then ask questions about your code here. One observation about what you have so far is that you have two types named `ab`. The second one of these will hide the first, so you can't use both at once. The two tree types will need to have different names.

Comment: sorry i didn't notice that my function didn't appear 
i edited so now it's fixed

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't seem to work"? In which way does it not work? How do you know? Do you except us to guess?

Comment: Can you show an example of input and expected output?

Comment: well i did in the picture  2-3-4 tree to bicolor

Answer (score 1):

If I enter your `eclat` function as you have it now, I get this:

> Hint: If this is a recursive definition, you should add the 'rec' keyword on line 1

So that's one problem.

I also note that you changed `ab` to `ab234`, but you didn't change the internal appearances inside the type. So the contents of the `ab234` type are all defined to be of type `ab`. This doesn't seem correct.